# copying a big CSV document data into a Word table that is much much smaller

Tags: ms-word

I have a small table in word with 5 rows and 4 columns.

I have a CSV document with 100 rows and 4 columns.

I want to copy / paste the CSV data into the table.

How do I do that without haveing to create all of the rows in the table ahead of time and then pasting?

I can only see a way to Insert one row at a time in word into the table??
How can I specify the size of the table?? Table properites does not let you control that??
Or is there a way to automatically increase the size of your table if you're pasting something bigger.

Comment: Hello, the most efficient way to create a table of data in a Word document is to concatenate the data into a delimited string, assign it to a document range, and then convert the range to a table, as described in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to append the data after the 5th row, you can select the CSV data in Excel (minus the header rows), copy it, then paste it into the Word document on the line immediately following the table; i.e. not the fifth row, but the first line directly below the fifth row. Word should append the data as rows to the table automatically.

I used Excel 2007 and Word 2007 on Windows 7 to test this. It only works if the data you paste has the same number of columns as the Word table.

Hope this helps!